# Cannot assign JSON value to JS variable

Tags: javascript, json

I am building a YT mp3 downloader. I'm using API from youtubeinmp3. This is how I am getting the download link in JSON format.

[image: JSON data from API?]

I am using this to assign the JSON value for "link" to JS Variable ytdlink.
But it's not working, the value for ytdlink is getting set to "function link() { [native code] }".

```
function getyt()
            {
            var a = document.getElementById("mquery").value;
                $.get(
                    "http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?format=JSON",
                    {
                        video:a
                    },function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    var ytdlink = data.link;
                    });

            }
```

How do I assign the link to a JS variable?

Comment: $.get has a fourth parameter "dataType" which you should set to "json".  Right now you're getting a string.

Comment: @James It should be intelligently guessing and converting it to JSON already as per [the docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Comment: @mhodges It should be, but it's not.  Why in your answer are you suggesting to separately parse the string to an object if it should already be done?

Comment: @James My previous comment was more-so inquisitive of why it was not automatically converting it. I wonder if it has to do with the escaped characters in the `link` value? I'm honestly not sure..

Comment: youtubeinmp3.com is returning a Content-Type of text/html instead of application/json, is probably why.  Note that setting json using the fourth parameter will force the conversion.

Comment: @mhodges Gave the correct method to assign it.

Comment: @James solution to force the data type will work just as well, for anyone looking in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [`link` is a function on the String prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/link) and you are working with a JSON string, that is why it is spitting out

> function link() { [native code] }

You must use `JSON.parse()` on your `data` in order to access the properties like so:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
var ytdlink = obj.link;
```